# regex to curly braces on their own or with the 'else' word

Tags: java, regex, curly-braces

I'm trying to to write some custom definitions for the code counting tool `cloc`, but unfortunately regular expressions are not my strong point.

I'm struggling to write a regex that will match lines containing only whitespace before and/or after `{` or `}`

I also need to match lines that contain white space and `}` followed by the keyword `else`

i.e. in the following sample:

```
1  if ( some condition ) {
2     do something
3  } else if ( some other condition ) {
4     do this
5  } else {
6     do this
7  }
8  
9  if ( some other condition ) 
10 {
11   do this
12 }
```

I need a regex that would match lines 5, 7, 10 and 12.

I started with a very simple `\s*{`  but this matches against lines that contains words as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex follows your outlined specifications:

```
String regex = "\\s*[{}]\\s*|\\s*\\}\\s*else.*";
```

It matches lines containing either:

- `0` or more spaces, followed by `{` or `}`, followed by 0 or more spaces

  *or*
- `0` or more spaces, followed by a `}`, then `0` or more spaces, then `else`, then anything.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex would match lines consisting of more instance of the following: `whitespaces`, `{`, `}` or the word `else` components, but nothing else:

```
^(?:[\s{}]|else)+$
```